# How to plot a Circle with sin cos and pi

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

My professor wants me to plot a circle using `matplotlib` using sin, cos and pi.

I have looked at several threads and videos on the net but I just get no clue on how to solve the problem

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r=5
t= np.arange(math.pi,-math.pi, 0.1)
x=r*math.sin(t);
y=r*math.cos(t);
plt.plot(x,y)
```

This is what I tried but I get the following error

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1) You need to use the `sin` and `cos` from NumPy as the `math` versions do not provide vectorized operations. You can also use `pi` from NumPy thereby removing `import math`

2) You need to use `np.arange(-np.pi,np.pi, 0.1)` i.e., start from negative number and go to positive in steps of 0.1. Otherwise, use `-0.1` in your actual code.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r=5
t= np.arange(-np.pi,np.pi, 0.1)
x=r*np.sin(t);
y=r*np.cos(t);
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axis('equal')
```

[image]

If you want to have a complete circle, you can use

```
t= np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
```

[image]